# Fresh installation of Magento 2 - store loads fine, admin login fails with CURLPROTO_HTTP error

Tags: magento2

Fresh Magento2 manual installation on Ubuntu 16.04. Store with samples displays fine. Admin page with user and password displays fine too.

Once credentials are entered and trying to login, getting

> There has been an error processing your request error on page and "Error log record number: 714486746083".

In the `log/report` folder of my Magento installation, I can see the error:

> {"0":"Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLPROTO_HTTP - assumed 'CURLPROTO_HTTP' in /var/www/myserverexample.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50","1".."

I checked:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
php7.1-curl is already the newest version (7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 299 not upgraded
```

Permissions:
[image: magento folder screenshot]
Any suggestion?

Comment: did you find any solution I having this issue !

Answer (score 2):

- php 7.1: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl`
- php 7.2: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl`
- php 7.3: `sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl`
- php 7.4: `sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl`

may resolve your issue

Comment: before php-curl make sure your system has curl, sudo apt-get install curl

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.
You probably don't have the php-curl extension installed or if you do it's for the wrong Php version. Try reinstalling the extension.
[This doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html) tells you all the required Php extensions as a system requirement.